# Problem with loading local images added in object array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I made a #JS file called SliderImgs and put an array of objects in that which includes the properties of images of a slider:

```
const Images=[
    {
        src:'./files/new-banner-high.jpg',
        alt:'banner',
        order:'0'
    }
]
export default Images
```

Then I imported this array to a component and then passed that (the array) from props to another component called Slider

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Images from './SliderImgs'
import Slider from './Slider'

 class Body extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="slider">
          <Slider pictures={Images}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Body
```

and finally tried to Print the Image on the screen using the  map() method, but I got this error:
**Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './files/new-banner-high.jpg'**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

 class Slider extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
          pictures:[]
        }
     }
     static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
      return {pictures : props.pictures }
    ;
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="slidercontainer">
          {this.state.pictures.map((picture, index)=> {
              return(
                  <img src={require(picture.src)} alt={picture.alt} key={index} />
              )
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Slider
```

Comment: is the `files` folder  in `public` folder?

Comment: It is inside src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally images should be kept in the public folder.

1. Move the `files` directory to the `public` folder.
2. Change the array as below.

```
const Images=[
    {
        src:'/files/new-banner-high.jpg',
        alt:'banner',
        order:'0'
    }
]
```

3. Change the `img` element like below.

```
<img src={picture.src} alt={picture.alt} key={index} />
```